# How to export rigged character with ik or fk with .fbx format

Tags: rigging, export, inverse-kinematics

I want to export my 3d modal with ik in .fbx format. I also try this with export my rigged character with .fbx format but it`s IK is not working after import it again.

One more problem is ik bone become double after import it in blender. I also check it in maya, there also same problem Ik not working.

Any one can tell me that, How can i export working ik or fk with .fbx.?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. Supporting basic bone animation is already a total nightmare, so we are not even remotely close to start dreaming about supporting things like constraints or IK in FBX (not totally sure FBX does support IK, actually…).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an open source Blender addon that converts your IKs rig into an FK rig with the exact same poses. You can then export your new FK rig.

Hope it helps! https://github.com/chinedufn/blender-iks-to-fks